# What context are Jest tests invoked in?

Tags: jestjs

I'm migrating a rather large test suite from Mocha to Jest. In Mocha, the tests are executed with the same context, so the test suite makes heavy use of `this`  to store information set up in `before`/`beforeEach` blocks, e.g. :

```
beforeEach(function(){   
  this.foo = 'bar'; 
});

it('does the thing', function(){
  expect(this.foo).toEqual('bar');
});
```

In using Jest, however, I haven't been able to figure out if the tests are invoked with a consistent context or if I should have the expectation of a consistent context. When playing around with tests on [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/jest), the do appear to be invoked with a consistent context, but when doing it locally, I've experienced inconsistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Jest restricts context to test/before/after function scope. If you want to share something between these, use a global variable.